# This execute() function in QT is running multiple times i.e. it is sending POST request multiple times, that causing multiple request and response

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, event-loop, qnetworkaccessmanager

This execute() method in QT is running multiple times i.e. it is sending POST request multiple times, that causing multiple request and response. While debugging I found out that after executing eventloop, it is again coming back to the function in which I am using execute method.

```
QJsonObject WebServiceRequestor::execute(QString aServiceURL, QByteArray aJSONRequest, QString aHeaderType,
                                         WebMethod_E aMethod, int aNetworkTimeout)
{

    QJsonDocument replyJSON;
    QJsonObject jsonObj;

    QTimer timer;
    QEventLoop eventLoop;

    if( aNetworkTimeout == 0 )
    {
        aNetworkTimeout = AppSettings::getStateInt(ask::NETWORK_TIMEOUT);
        if(aNetworkTimeout < al::NETWORK_TIMEOUT_THRESHOLD)
        {
            AppSettings::setState(ask::NETWORK_TIMEOUT, al::NETWORK_TIMEOUT_VALUE, false);
            aNetworkTimeout = al::NETWORK_TIMEOUT_VALUE.toInt();
        }

    timer.setSingleShot(true);
    connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), &eventLoop, SLOT(quit()));

    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl(QUrl(aServiceURL));
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, aHeaderType);

    timer.start(aNetworkTimeout);

    QNetworkReply* reply  = 0;

    if( aMethod == POST )
    {
        reply = pNetworkAccessManager_->post(request, aJSONRequest);
    }else
    {
        reply = pNetworkAccessManager_->get(request);
    }

    // Connect finished signal before calling get/post. The connect can be written after the get/post call and
    // before the event loop exec as the method is not called till the event loop is not executed.
    QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &eventLoop, SLOT(quit()), Qt::UniqueConnection);

    // Will wait in event loop till we receive response from server or timer defined above times out

    eventLoop.exec();

    // Stop timer as event loop has exited
    timer.stop();

    reply->deleteLater();
    return jsonObj;
}
```